# Proper way to Implement Dark Theme Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-dark-theme

I am learning how to implement Dark Theme to application.
After reading documents from [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme), below are the requirements that I understand

1. make sure "**Style**" parent = `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">`
2. create a new colors for Dark Theme in side colors.xml file
3. if using "**Switch**" toggle, use `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);` and `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);` inside `onCheckedChanged` listener

Based on testing, calling `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);` will trigger `recreate()` to recreate the activity, result it will change the theme as expected, also the BLACK blinking thingy will appear.

After reading through [this](https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/daynight-theme-android-tutorial-example/), it stated that I need to declare `setTheme` method before      `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` so it will solve the BLACK thingy issue.

The Android Dev document does not mentioned anything about `setTheme` is required in `OnCreate` method after `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);` is used

1. If using only `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);` able to switch desire theme, what's the point of using `setTheme` again in `onCreate` method?
2. Is the BLACK blinking thing a bug? or is there a proper way to solve it?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ UPDATE ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Maybe my questions is confusing as well. To make it short, just wanted to know that why "setTheme" is needed to declared in `onCreate` when `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)` already restarted the acitivy?

I'm so confused and spent more than a week to solve this, guidance or tips are much appreciated

Comment: What is "the BLACK blinking thingy"? The screen flashing black as it is re-created?

Comment: @TylerV yes, the screen will flash when changing the screen. It confirmed that it will call the recreate native method. I cant seems to find the right way to solve it

Comment: You may need it ib `onCreate` if you want to save it upon restarting of the app.

Comment: @dan1st, I knew that we need to use SharedPreferences for "Resume" or upon "Restarting" the app, but I'm confused that why need "setTheme" again in "OnCreate" when "AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);" already doing already?

Comment: Where does it say you need to use it in `onCreate` and `onResume` instead of just one of them?

Comment: @dan1st sorry if I made confusion for my answer. if you see below answer from "Gourav Gautam". It stated that "Change App theme on Activity on create method using shared prefrence" which means that I need to use "setTheme" again in "OnCreate" method. To be clear , nothng will be added in "OnResume" or "OnRestart"

Answer (score 3):

The AppCompactDelegate some times recreates the activity that causes black blinking

Check This It Changes theme without black blinking

Create two themes or use default dark theme xml like this :

```
<!--  Dark theme  -->

<style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

<item name="colorPrimary">@color/darkColorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkColorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="fontFamily">@font/roboto</item>
<item name="listBackground">@color/darkListBackground</item>
<item name="cardBackground">@color/darkCardBackground</item>
<item name="textColor">@color/darkCardTitle</item>
<item name="actionBarBackgroundColor">@color/darkColorPrimary</item>
<item name="actionBarTextColor">@color/darkCardTitle</item>
<item name="dialogTextColor">@color/darkDialogTitle</item>
<item name="dialogDateColor">@color/dialogDateColor</item>
</style>


<!--  Light theme  -->

<style name="LightTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

<item name="colorPrimary">@color/lightColorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/lightColorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="fontFamily">@font/roboto</item>
<item name="listBackground">@color/lightListBackground</item>
<item name="cardBackground">@color/lightCardBackground</item>
<item name="textColor">@color/lightCardTitle</item>
<item name="actionBarBackgroundColor">@color/lightColorPrimary</item>
<item name="dialogTextColor">@color/lightDialogTitle</item>
<item name="dialogDateColor">@color/dialogDateColor</item>
</style>
```

Use Shared Prefrence to save themes type

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("NightMode", false);
        editor.apply();
```

Change App theme on Activity on create method using shared prefrence

```
 if (!darktheme) {
            setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
        } else {
            setTheme(R.style.LightTheme);
        }
```

For Brief Information get that project :
https://github.com/yeshasmp/ToDo/tree/v1.0

Comment: thanks for the answer. This method is working as expected, but are there other method without using "setTheme"? I assume that using "setTheme" is not fully using "AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);" feature.

Why need to use "setTheme" in "OnCreate" when  "AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);" already apply "darktheme" automatically?

Answer (score 0):

In the folder structure of your project in the Android Studio version 4.1.1 (I think the solution may also apply to the near versions)check whether there reside two folders such that one for the light theme and one for the dark theme. Make sure the dropdown of the project tab is in project mode, not Android mode. Then check whether in the directory app>src>main>res there exist two folders named values and values-night. Expand those directories to see whether both folders contain a theme.xml file separately. If not just add a theme.xml file for the missing folder with the below code. This will set up the project to run in both light and dark modes with default values in the os. If you want you can customize by adding items inside style tags for action bar, status bar, etc. Make sure to replace ***AppName*** with your app name.By the way my gradle version is 4.1.1.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
   <style name="Theme.AppName" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
   </style>
</resources>
```